# RewriteEngine won't let my page execute corectly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to `.htaccess` and I am trying to rewrite my URLs to make them more friendly. Below is an example of the URL:

```
# without RewriteEngine
http://www.example.com/download.php?fid=123456
# with RewriteEngine
http://www.example.com/download/123456/
```

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/(\w+)/$ /download.php?fid=$1
```

If I go to this URL: `http://www.example.com/download/123456/`, the CSS file and other external inclusions on my page won't load. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is only matching `[a-z]` and you're passing digits after `/download/`. You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/(\w+)/?$ /download.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`\w` is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

For css/js etc. use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Alternatively you can also try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: I had `(\w+)` before, but I changed it. Before, the result was the same. Also, I see `[L,QSA]` in your code. Can you explain it, please?